# PGAdmin 4 fails to backup database with no errors

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pg-dump, pgadmin-4

I try to backup my university project database. I followed the instruction, everything seems to be inputed:

1:

[image]

2:

[image]

3:

But the only pop-out I get is this one in right-bottom corner of PGAdmin 4:
[image]

From the [Official site](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs4/dev/backup_dialog.html), there should be another pop-up message, similiard to this one:

[image]

But I don't get this one, nor I get the other one that is displayed where any error occurs.

I tried to directly use **pg_dump.exe**, but it prompts me for a password. I tried all my passwords - user password, server password which I use to connect to my database in PGAdmin 4, other passwords, but none of them seem to work.

[image]

I tried to find any information about this, but all articles about **pg_dump.exe** are about how to automatize password input. What is the cause of this backup silent failure, and *which* password does **pg_dump.exe** need?

I'll add any details if needed, I was trying to figure it out for 4 hours now...

Comment: `pg_dump` uses the current operating system user if you don't provide one (the actual username is part of the error message but your [screen shot](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) cut  that off). Use the `-U` parameter to specify the same username you use in pgAdmin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you upgrade your pgAdmin4 with version 1.2 and try again?
https://www.pgadmin.org/

I think they have fixed the issue in new release.

Answer (score 6):

I've tried with pgAdmin4 1.4 and still my backup file was empty so I moved back to pgAdmin3 and it worked like a charm.
Although pgAdmin3 is not maintained anymore I suggest you use it until pgAdmin4 is up to it but right now it is way too slow.

Comment: On PGAmin 1.5 same problem. Se a job created by no backup actually done.

Answer (score 1):

Clearing the items in the path: `C:\Users\yourUser\AppData\Roaming\pgAdmin` seems to do the trick. Tested on PGadmin 4.29.

Be aware that all the sessions and saved servers will be gone.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had twoversions of Postgresql installed and I was trying to use the wrong pgadmin.