# pgadmin backup Failed (exit code: 500)

Tags: postgresql, backup, pgadmin, bigsql

Trying to backup any postgresql database but got this error, right after pressing backup button. I need to make back up in pgadmin. I have tried many variants pgadmin 3,4 - same error. Now i am on bigsql's `pgdevops` , but same error. Maybe something with linux roles, access rights? I am using linux mint 18.2
Here is the Error message: [image]

If i need some tricks with rights, where should it be done? I just starting `./pgc start pgdevops` wehre should i check/set rights?

Comment: Edit the question to show the full error. Also check if the backup user has required permissions or not

Comment: You need to be / have Super User privs for back ups.

Comment: @Mokadillion , what do yuo mean?  i have all rights, ican run pgadmin with sudo, i can run any command with sudo, but nothing works

Comment: have you tried backing up connected as the database user using pgsql commands ?

Comment: @Mokadillion yes i tried backup and restore with commands from terminal- it works, but i need to make backups with pgadmin

Comment: this maybe a pgadmin issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42462827/pgadmin-4-fails-to-backup-database-with-no-errors One response is that its a version error. Are your versions up to date ?

Comment: @Mokadillion i tried many versions and latest tott